# Detecting database server type

Tags: php, база-данных

В двух словах, есть ли способ определить тип БД, которая находится по данному ip адресу используя чистый PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете приложение, которое решает иные задачи, чем сканирование сети, то ответственность по использованию корректных настроек лежит на модуле конфигурации и пользователе, вводящем эти настройки. Ваше приложение не должно сканировать серверы и тыкаться на предмет подходящего сервака БД.

Я серьезно: это не мимокрокодил-совет и не рандомная фраза, если вы занимаетесь вышеописанным, то вы занимаетесь не делом.

Comment: Грубо говоря, пишу легкий mvc фрэймворк, хотелось бы реализовать механизм автоматического определения типа серверов. Час больше действий требуется от разработчика - тем хуже.

Comment: Окей, нашли вы SQL Server. Что дальше? Это тот сервер, который нужен? Какую сеть вы будете сканировать? Весь интернет? Подсеть, определенную по маске? А если это сильно удаленный сервер?

Comment: Видимо, меня неправильно поняли. Пользователь вводит ip адрес сервера бд, имя юзверя и пароль. Система сама определяет какой драйвер бд требуется использовать

Comment: Окей, хорошо, на одном сервере подняты Mysql и Postgresql. Действия фреймворка?

Comment: Выбирать по списку приоритета, либо ожидать действий от разработчика, кидая исключение. UPD я не прошу разбираться в механике работы, но прошу помочь с механизмом определения.

Comment: При каждом запросе ожидать действий от разработчика? Разница DSN  тех же mysql и постгрю - это, в общем случае, пять символов. Поверьте, то что вы делаете, представляет максимум академический интерес.

Comment: Я не задавал вопрос о механизме взаимодействия. Мне нужен конкретный ответ на возможной реализации определения. А уже само взаимодействие с полученными данными оставьте на мое усмотрение, мне не интересно ваше мнение по этому поводу.

Comment: *прошу помочь с механизмом определения* в принципе, по умолчанию перечисленные серверы слушают разные tcp-порты: [mysql — 3306, ms sql — 1433, postgresql — 5432](http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/ports.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Способ, конечно, есть. Ведь php — полноценный язык программирования.

Посмотрите, как реализовано детектирование, например, в nmap ([mysql](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/mysql-info.html) и [ms-sql](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ms-sql-info.html)) и реализуйте алгоритм на php.